# Terraform: How to split output of a resource and pass it as input

Tags: terraform

If I output

```
cloudamqp_instance.rabbitmq.url
```

I'll get

```
amqps://test:xxxxxxxxxxx@young-white.rmq2.cloudamqp.com/test
```

now I have to pass substring from above output like this

```
provider "rabbitmq" {
  endpoint = "https://young-white.rmq2.cloudamqp.com"
  username = "test"
  password = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

Is there a way to do that??

Comment: There are a few String functions you can use to split the string etc and get the values you need. You probably will need a combination of them: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/split.html. There is also a regex function.

Comment: Split won't work I tired. I think regex is the only option but terraform don't support all regex option only R2 engine. which I am not able to figure out.

Comment: Sure split works. You just need to split multiple times, which is cumbersome. As I said, you will need a combination of functions. For example to get `young-white.rmq2.cloudamqp.com` you split at the `@` and the result you split at the `/` and voila. It won't be pretty, but it will work. But I guess regex is the better option.

Comment: How did it go? Did you manage to check the regex I provided?

Comment: Yes. It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your example is actually representative of your use-case, the following `regex` can parse it:

```
variable "s" {
  default = "amqps://test:xxxxxxxxxxx@young-white.rmq2.cloudamqp.com/test"
}

locals {
  parsed = regex(".+//(?P<username>.+):(?P<password>.+)@(?P<endpoint>.+)/", var.s)
}

output "test" {
  value = local.parsed
}
```

which gives:

```
test = {
  "endpoint" = "young-white.rmq2.cloudamqp.com"
  "password" = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
  "username" = "test"
}
```

Then you have to just add `https://` to `local.parsed.endpoint`